# What does grid-row: 1 do?

Tags: css, css-grid

I don't understand how `grid-row: 1` works from the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) - it doesn't describe single-value syntax. What does giving it a value of `1` do? (Same goes for `grid-column: 1`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid-row` is shorthand for `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end`.

One can pass in both values like `1/3`. First value is the start line and the secondvalue is the end line, in a grid-based design.

In case second value is omitted, then the element will take 1 box.

This is, starting at first line and ending at third line. Which means `1 / 3`.

Imagine the box divided in horizontal lines, and it will look something like this if the first box has the style `grid-row : 1 / 3`
[image]

This is, starting at first line and spanning 1 box. Which means `1`:

Imagine the box divided in horizontal lines, and it will look something like this if the first box has the style `grid-row : 1`
[image]

[Read this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#grid-columngrid-row)

Comment: This part in the CSS Tricks article you linked cleared things up. "If no end line value is declared, the item will span 1 track by default."

Answer (score 1):

So according to MDN its a shorthand for `grid-row-start` and
`grid-row-end`

by "line" i mean the horizontal lines:

`grid-row: 1;`  start on 1st grid line, height is one row

`grid-row: 1 / 3;`  start 1st grid line, ends on 3rd grid line

`grid-row: 2 / -1;`  start 2nd grid line, ends on "-1" grid line(last grid line)

`grid-row: 1 / span 2;;`  start 1st grid line, height is two rows

`grid-column` does the similar, with the vertical lines being considered and calculated.